# how do i change one image to another image?

Tags: android

In my application i created an image view programatically. I created same type of 10 images dynamically. whenever i click the image i want to change the  image to another image and If I press it again it turns to previous image. I wrote code for this. But whenever i click the particular image the change is applied to another image.

```
 im = new ImageView(this);
   @Override
    public  void onClick(View v) {

        boolean flag = true;



       for (int k=0;k<sheetdetails.size();k++){

            if(sheetdetails.get(k).get("SeatNo").equalsIgnoreCase(v.getTag().toString())&&sheetdetails.get(k).get("IsAvailable").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

                if(flag)
                {       
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat);
                    flag=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.selectedseat);
                    flag=true;
                }              


            }

            }


    }
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere you are setting to a different image. Can you please clarify where you are setting

Comment: previously it is seat image after click it will changed to selected seat and vice versa  (setting with flag)

Comment: You set the flag to true **every time you click**. So, it's **always true**. Better move that instruction outside. Other than this (assuming you set the onClick() in the xml layout), you declare **1 ImageView only**, not 10. And you **don't distinguish which** one has been clicked.

Comment: i initialize boolean as true as first time

Comment: In the **wrong place**. You do it on **every click**.

Comment: @KartheekiJampana so it alwys true in onClick.you need to use getTag() and setTag() of View for this.

Comment: so how can i do it now, please tellme

Comment: @KartheekiJampana what you are maintaining in View.setTag() method??

Comment: that is the condition for only available true seats only clickable

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the program does the if branch as well as the else branch, because you enter the method with flag = true;

```
if(flag)
            {       
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat);
                flag=false;
            }
else
            {
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.selectedseat);
                flag=true;
            }
```

so you enter the first if, there you set the flag false, so you also enter afterwards the else branch. Either you change the flow of your program or you initialize a temporary variable.

When you do it that way, the if/else construct is unnecessary, because you enter both every time.

Comment: Exactly, I just wanted to show you the mistake/problem, because there is no sense behind this if/else construct. If you need a if branch, it would be better to use a temporary variable in the right way.

Comment: so how can i solve my problem.could you please tell me

Comment: So if I understand you in the right way, you have for example two images and if image one is visible and is getting clicked, the other image should be shown. Right? If yes, then just scan for the picture name, which is active and return the other picture.

Comment: for example i have 10 images which are created dynamically. From the 10 images whenever i click any particular image that image will be turn to image2. after that whenever i clicked to image2 it need to  be changed as previous image (vice versa)

Comment: @KartheekiJampana what you are maintaining in View.setTag() method??what is seat number data??

Comment: Ah okay, so you want to switch two images from a set of images. A easy way to do this, will be that you save the state (firstClick or secondClick) in a boolean variable, so that you know if an image is already selected. And secondly you just have to save the images in an ArrayList which has an own switch method. Just try it!

Comment: i want to apply the condition for only available seats are true. thats y i wrote that condition

Comment: i tried...but the change is applied to another image.

Comment: @KartheekiJampana nope i am using your clicked imageView.no way to change the another image